# "How does that fit into cost per square meter?"

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the diary of Alistar Skinner, a young artist dying of colon cancer, as quoted by Sîan Ede on [p. 150 of *Art and Science*](https://books.google.com/books?id=xCkBAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA150&ots=E_d6LsI9Yx&dq=Awake%20at%20dawn%20to%20go%20to%20the%20toilet%2C%20I%20hear%20the%20black%20birds%20singing%20in%20the%20quiet&pg=PA150#v=onepage&q=blackbirds&f=false), we read:

> *Awake at dawn to go to the toilet, I hear the black birds singing in the quiet of the urban night and it is lovely. How does that fit into cost per square meter?*

Does "*How does that fit into cost per square meter?*" mean:

1. How much will actually the birds' song cost per meter square

or

2. How can one actually measure the beautiful birds' song with soulless and ugly scales like cost per square?

Comment: Can anyone really evaluate the bird's song in dollar or whatever currency? It is invaluable.

Comment: Why are you asking? If you can identify the second meaning it's clear that it's not the first.

Comment: @curiousdannii  Yes, I know what it means. I wanted to know which way the writer is expressing it. Is he with some degree of satire thinking to himself that "how much birds' song cost actually"? or is he directly expressing that "it is not equivalent to anything else"? Both have the same meaning but the way of their expression is different.

Comment: @user127733 That comment doesn't make any sense. You know what he means, and he's expressing it precisely as he has expressed it in the passage you quoted. I just went to Google Books: the entire context is about the objectification of human life, and the application of quantification to the immeasurable.  I don't see how you can have any uncertainty.  BTW, I fixed it on your behalf this time, but in the future, please *always attribute quoted material*. Not only is it ethical and proper, it will give us more context to provide you with better answers.

Comment: @Dan Bron  OK. Thank you very much both for editing the question (adding details) and for your answer to it.

Comment: "Cost per square meter" implies an accountant or other number-cruncher placing a value on everything.  The individual quoted is being sarcastic, as there is no way to place a value on such things.

Comment: @HotLicks Well, the individual being quoted is dying of colon cancer; the quote is from the diary he kept of his own dying process.  He's likely being more morose or melancholy than sarcastic.

Comment: @DanBron Reading the context you have just shown, I think the writer wants to buy it to keep it in his room 24/7 as the birds don't sing every minute.

Comment: @Rathony I don't think the writer wants to buy anything; he's dying, and he knows it. As awesome as any apartment is, you can't take it with you when you go.

Comment: @DanBron - You can read it as "ironic" rather than "sarcastic" if you wish.  Though perhaps "sardonic" would be better still.

Comment: @HotLicks Yeah, I think "sardonic" is spot-on.  The guy is probably pissed at the unfairness of it all.

Comment: @DanBron Or he wants to calculate how much the lovely environment the birds are creating has been factored into the cost of his apartment, feeling it's a good thing that I bought or rented this house. I would have paid more with it"

Comment: @Rathony That idea had crossed my mind too, but more in the cynical "I wonder if the landlords noticed the lovely dawn chorus of the blackbirds and worked that into my rent, too" way.

Answer (score 1):

He refers to the "urban night", which implies that he lives in an apartment or house in a city.  Whether purchased or rented, housing costs are measured in terms of *cost per square (foot/meter)*.  This cost is usually justified by benefits of the neighborhood like quality of schools, accessible transportation and shopping, low crime rate, etc.

In his waning days, your doomed artist is taking in the simple beauties in his surroundings, and noting that there is no way the music of the birds could be factored into the cost of his home.

A free gift of the universe.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that recently the artist had been quoted some product (Let's say drawing paper or canvas for example) at a cost per square meter.  Such things have a material value, for example the cost of raw materials, production and distribution, but they also have other value. A picture by a good artist is worth much more than the cost of paper, pencils and paints that it is made from. A painting by Picasso or van Gogh may be worth millions per square meter.

A songbird takes up very little space in the world and uses very few resources—yet the value of its song to an appreciative human is out of all proportion to its physical presence.

Comment: He may just be assuming that the commonplace (and clamorous) is _so_ commonplace that it needs no further contextualising. cf 'What does that have to do with the price of tea in China?'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I don't understand the point you are making.

Comment: '(I imagine that) recently the artist had been quoted some product' need not reflect the actual situation. He might be making more intellectual demands on the reader in supplying their own context.